# apply security=none to context root and static resources : spring security version 3.1

Tags: spring-security

my application compiles to ROOT.war which basically means I do not have a context root other than /. There are pages which are to be secured; however there are URLs which do not need it; for example my http://localhost:8080/ gives the home page of this application; and there are similar pages like about us, contact us, etc where security is not need. So I add this to the configuration

```
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/register/confirm" access="isAuthenticated()" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/register/accept" access="isAuthenticated()" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/shopper/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

but this just says that users are allowed to access these URL "without authentication"if you access these URLs the security filters are all applied, as seen below in the debug logs

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OpenIDAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [permitAll]
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@2b06c17b, returned: 1
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing GET request for [/
```

]

When I try using this configuration (in sequence mentioned below):

```
 <!-- No Security required for the ROOT Context -->
  <security:http pattern="/**" security="none" />

 <!-- Apply secyrity for shopper URLs -->
 <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/denied">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/register/confirm" access="isAuthenticated()" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/register/accept" access="isAuthenticated()" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/shopper/**" access="isAuthenticated()" /
 ....
  </security:http>

<security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
```

It breaks down giving the error

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/auth/login'; against '/'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/auth/login'; against '/resources/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/auth/login'; against '/register/confirm'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/auth/login'; against '/register/accept'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/auth/login'; against '/shopper/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator - No access attributes defined for login page URL
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5bebacc8: defining beans [placeholderConfig,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,registrationService,shopperService,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,passwordEncoder,registrationAwareUserDetailsService,registrationAwareAuthSuccessHandler,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - closing
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http> namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
```

I cannot really understand the reason behind this. Do I have to implement my own request pattern matcher?

**Solution**

```
 <beans:bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy" >
 <beans:constructor-arg>
  <beans:list>
   <security:filter-chain pattern="/resources/**"
    filters="none" />
   <security:filter-chain pattern="/aboutus"
    filters="none" />   
   <security:filter-chain pattern="/contactus"
    filters="none" />
   <security:filter-chain pattern="/news"
    filters="none" />    
  </beans:list>
 </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`security="none"` with pattern `/**` captures all URLs, so no other rule could be applied. What's why you receive error in second example.

But it's possible to define different `filter-chains` for different URL-patterns. I don't have example of this with new syntax, but here is example with old syntax (order of `filter-chains` is important):

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/dwr/**" filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter,securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,anonymousAuthenticationFilter" />
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="channelProcessingFilter,securityContextPersistenceFilter,logoutFilter,authenticationFilter,securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,anonymousAuthenticationFilter,sessionManagementFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,filterSecurityInterceptor,switchUserProcessingFilter" />
    </sec:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

Comment: **Update:** Going by the answer I removed the first tag i.e.

     <!-- No Security required for the ROOT Context -->
      <security:http pattern="/**" security="none" />

the second one remains .i.e. the configuration for resources; but I still get the same error.

Comment: You said that you receive same message containing phrase `A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns`? Maybe you forgot to redeploy?

Comment: TO be precise; there are URLs where I do not want any sort of filters to apply; I see it as unnecessary steps in request processing and want to do away with it.

Comment: I am running from Eclipse so I cleaned and republished before starting the tomcat server again.

Comment: **Solved**: added filters=none in the configuration for filter chain proxy for the URL patters I wanted to exclude. Similar to the approach you said but 3.1.0 has a constructor argument injection based syntax

Comment: I found example with new syntax and `filters="none"`. Looks a bit better, so you could try this one too.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the syntax I have finally chosen to stick with; for it makes the XML a lot easier to read and comprehend

```
 <!-- Non secure URLs -->
 <security:http pattern="/" security='none' /> 
 <security:http pattern="/home" security='none' />
 <security:http pattern="/aboutus" security='none' />
 ...
 ...
 <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security='none' />
 <security:http pattern="/favicon.ico" security='none' />

 <!-- URLs under security config -->
  <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/admin/**" access-denied-page="/denied">
         <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https" />
  </security:http>
```