# Spring Security url-interceptor leak at /*

Tags: spring-security

Spring Security 2.x is intercepting `http:servername/webAppName`. Based on my understanding the `filter="none"` should discard any Spring Security filter chain for the URL that do not require access role. Anybody knows why this setup is intercepting all URLs that are not declared (`/listing`, `/load`) including the base URL?

```xml
<http auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="entryPoint" session-fixation-protection="none">
    <intercept-url pattern="/listing/pages/*" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/load/page/*" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/secret/*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" filters="none"/>
    <http-basic/>
</http>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513688/apply-security-none-to-context-root-and-static-resources-spring-security-versi

Comment: Thanks. will see if I can have something similar. the link covers spring security  3.1

Answer (score -1):

Try This,

```
<security:http auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="entryPoint" session-
fixation-protection="none">
<http-basic/>
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/secret/*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/listing/pages/*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/load/page/*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
</security:http>
```

and yes, check your xmlns namespace for spring security, is that fine ?

Comment: <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd"> 
    ...
</beans:beans>

Comment: for testing purpose I replaced as you mention and ended up having an infinite loop. access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" doesn't discard the filter chain and an added customize filter will throw an exception if the request header is missing information from the site minder. The aim here is to skip the filter chain. Below are my name spaces.

Comment: @MAXStack if you just want to skip the Filter chain(though not recommended) then just do something like bellow : write your own custom filter by extending the GenericFilterBean and there just perform your business task  and just remove the call to filterChain.doFilter(request, response) method.   if want to see an Example for Writing the custom filter, check my other Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43474961/6838178

Comment: Thanks for the tip. a custom filter is already in place using the filter class AstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter. I was able to fix all url except for the base. so I guess I will end up adding it on my logic as an exception. Again thanks a bunch